# Two games in one: Roll the dice and Bingo

Tags: python, function, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am developing a program that has an opening menu with two games: Roll the dice and Bingo. I am currently working on the roll the dice portion. At the moment I am stuck on how to add a piece of code in roll function that adds all of the user's rolls together. I would also like to create a loop where the else statement is in the roll_dice function that sends the user to the main menu if they enter N.

```
# Import
import random

def main():
    result = opening_menu()
    if result == 1:
        roll_dice()



# Opening menu
def opening_menu():

    print('In this program you may pick from the two games listed below. \n'
          'Just type the number next to option of your choosing.')
    print('\n')
    print('1: Roll some dice.')
    print('2: Play some Bingo.')
    print('3: Quit')
    option = int(input('What would you like to do? '))
    while option < 1 or option > 3:
        print('Please pick an option from the menu.')
        option = int(input('What would you like to do? ')) 
    return option

def roll_dice():
    rolling = True
    while rolling:

        answer = input('Are you ready to roll? Enter Y/N or any other key to quite: ')
        # Accept lower and upper case
        if answer.lower() =='y':

            die = int(input('Please enter the number of dice you wish to roll: '))
            while die <= 0:
                print('Invalid number.')
                die = int(input('Please enter the number of dice you wish to roll: '))

            sides = int(input('Next, enter the number of sides on your dice: '))
            while sides < 6:
                print('Invalid number.')
                sides = int(input('Enter the number of sides on your dice: '))

            roll(die, sides)
        else:
            print('Thank you for playing')
            break

# Roll the dice
def roll(dice, sides):
    # Start with 0
    r = 0
    # roll based on number of dice
    while r < dice:
        # Store random roll variable
        rolls = random.randint(1, sides)
        # Increase r by one each loop
        r += 1
        # Print rolls
        print('You rolled a:', rolls)
        

main()
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can store the values of each roll in a list, then use `sum()` on the list.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, Correct. I used a wrong variable, there. Similar to the way OP adds up the number of times, he can add up the roles. `total_roles += roles`.

Comment: Similar to the way you add up the number of times, you can add up the rolls. `total_rolls += rolls`. Also, for an input `'N'`, you can call `main()` before `break` in the `else` clause.

Comment: I have something to that effect, however I am trying to figure out where to put it, I keep getting "local variable 'total' referenced before assignment.

Comment: calling `main()` works just as I was hoping, Thank you!